# How to avoid sprintf warning for uint8_t data type

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

My questions are based on the snippets below:

```
    [line1] #include <stdio.h>
    .
    .
    .
    [line123] uint8_t msg[100];
    [line124] memset(msg,0,sizeof(msg));
    [line125] sprintf(msg,"SYSCLK : %ld\r\n",HAL_RCC_GetSysClockFreq());
    [line126] HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,msg,strlen(msg),HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    .
    .
    .
    [line130] char msg1[100];
    [line131] memset(msg1,0,sizeof(msg1));
    [line132] sprintf(msg1,"SYSCLK : %ldHz\r\n",HAL_RCC_GetSysClockFreq());
    [line133] HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,(uint8_t*)msg1,strlen(msg1),HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

1. Why does line 125 get a warning: " passing argument 1 of 'sprintf'
   from incompatible pointer type "
2. Refer to [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), I know that ...

   - **h** is a length modifier that applies to an unsigned short argument,
   - **hh** to an unsigned char, and
   - **z** to a size_t

...but doubt what **%ldHz** on line 132 means and why doesn't this line get a warning?

Thanks.

Comment: `Hz` isn't part of the format specifier.

Comment: What @FredLarson said: the `d` ends the format specifier, with "Hz" (Hertz) as literal text.

Comment: Images of code [are not acceptable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10077).

Comment: BTW, are you sure that `HAL_RCC_GetSysClockFreq()`  returns a `long int`? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763226/convert-dwt-cycle-count-to-time-using-stm32-and-hal)

Comment: Thanks Fred Larson, Steve Friedl and Bob__. @ Bob__ thanks for pointing it out. I've checked, it returns the value within long int range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does line 125 get a warning: " passing argument 1 of 'sprintf' from incompatible pointer type

`uint8_t` isn't necessarily directly compatible with `char` - the latter has implementation-defined signedness. `uint8_t` can however be safely converted to/from `char`, so you can try to cast with `(char*)msg` and see if that solves the problem.

> What does C print format specifier ' %ldHz ' mean?

The format specifier is `%ld` for type `long`, `Hz` is part of the output string (Hertz).

Comment: Undoubtedly, you meant to suggest casting to `char *`, not `char`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation and advice. After conversions, i got it all working with the following:                                                                                               
        sprintf((char*) msg, "SYSCLK : %ld\r\n", HAL_RCC_GetSysClockFreq());                                                        
 HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, msg, strlen((char*) msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

Answer (score 4):

The `Hz` is not part of the format specifier: it is simply printing the standard abbreviation for "Hertz" after the frequency value. So, the actual format specifier is just `%ld`, printing a long integer in decimal format.

Answer (score 3):

1. The first argument to `sprintf` is a `char *`.  You're passing in a `uint8_t *` (i.e. an `unsigned char *`).  That's a pointer type mismatch.
2. The actual format specifier is `%ld`.  The `Hz` that follows is just literal text that gets printed.

Comment: ad 1. This is how HAL drivers are written. They have not hears about `const` as well. Do not blame OP